# Prove the positive semi-definitness of a doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, number-theory, stochastic-processes, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

I want to prove the positive semi-definiteness of a $N\times N$ matrix A, where $a_{ij}=1-\rho\min\{|i-j|,N-|i-j|\}$, $|i-j|$ is the absolute difference between i and j, $\rho$ is a positive real number and all $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative. Then all diagonal elements of A are 1. By [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) I can show A's largest eigen-value (which is also A's spectral radius)is positive, but I have no idea to prove the positiveness of other eigen-values.

One way I tried before is to normalize A, since the sum of each of its rows and columns keeps the same and all A‘s elements are non-negative, therefore A could be a symmetric doubly stochastic matrix after normalization. While I still didn't find any way to solve it and all my simulation results show the eigen-values of A are non-negative. Any help? thank you so much.

Comment: note for small $\delta \gt 0$, consider  $P:=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf {11}^T\cdot (1+\delta) -\delta I$ is doubly stochastic and symmetric, but not positive semidefinite

Comment: yes, I know that symmetric, doubly stochatic matrix may not be psd, so I just focus on my special problem settings, in this problem, matrix A's should be psd while I didn't get the complete proof about it.